# how to send data to main wordpress plugin file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to develop a wordpress plugin. I have two file .For example `A.php` which is my main plugin php file and `B.php` which is another php file in the plugin directory.Now I need to send some data from `B.php` to `A.php` using a form with post method, but I receive `not defined 'ABSPATH' error` . How can I resolve this issue?
 
**Page A first line code:**
`defined ( 'ABSPATH' ) or die ( 'He He ');`
**Page B.php form code :**

```
echo '<form name="fr" action="'.$_GET['land'].'" method="post" >';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="success" value="'.$result->status.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.$result->amount.'" />';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="tranId" value="'.$transId.'" />';

echo '<script type="text/javascript" >';
echo 'document.fr.submit();';
echo '</script>';
echo '</form>';
```

**And the result is :**
`He He`

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: The `not defined 'ABSPATH'` error occurs when WordPress isn't loaded, which is why the server doesn't find WordPress functions. How is `A.php` being called?

Answer (score 0):

If you’re accessing a page directly (not through WordPress), and you want to use WordPress functions, you’ll need to include `wp-load.php`

```
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-load.php' );
```

This may help: [The simplest way to require/include wp-load.php](https://frankiejarrett.com/2012/04/the-simplest-way-to-require-include-wp-load-php/)

Comment: I tested it but same result :(

Comment: Which file did you add it to? And did you add it to the very top of that file (after `<?php`)?

Comment: I added it to page `B.php` at very top of file.

Comment: it loads `wp-load.php` successfully but gives `ABSPATH` error on page `A.php`